# How to change visualforce UI without redirecting the page or using flow:interview

Tags: visualforce

I have a visualforce page (importContacts) which will take users through two flows of screen. The first is to give an option of which type of contact i.e. temporary/permanent. Upon selecting from the selectRadio and clicking next button, I want to be able to display a table of contact based on the selection option without redirecting to a new page and without using flow:interview.

Answer (score 1):

The way I like to this is by using the rendered and reRender attributes.

```
<apex:form id='theForm>
    <apex:commandButton id='button' action="{!myAction}" reRender="theForm"/>
     // rendered if boolean variable in controller is true
     <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!displayQuestions}">

           //Your questions section goes here

     </apex:pageBlock>
     // rendered if boolean variable in controller is true
     <apex:pageBlock rendered={!displayContactList}>  

            //your contact list goes here

     </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:form>
```